# it is possible that the vb.net throws generic exceptions?

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-application-insights

I want to catch all the exceptions that the application launches with **[Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview)**, but I want to ignore the ones that developers are launching. I know it is incorrect but unfortunately the application has a complex mechanism for doing business validations through throwing exceptions, which will be resolved in the future ...

But as programmers are using the generic type, adding only one custom error message , my thinking was simple, collect all exceptions that are not generic type.

I just had a doubt, in some case vb.net launches exeções of the generic type?

I think not because I consider it bad practice, but I did not find any documentation to confirm this.

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Thank you for your attention Çöđěxě.

Normally .net throws exceptions of a certain type, for example "IndexOutOfRangeException", "NullReferenceException", etc ... in some circumstance it can throw exceptions of basic type "Exception"? Sorry, my ingueles are not the best

Comment: The chance is unlikely but it is hard to rule out. And even if the framework itself doesn't do it, other libraries that you import using NuGet for example might.

Comment: Do you want to collect only non-generic excptions(like IndexOutOfRangeException) in application insights?